# Array isn't free'd after going out of scope

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a simple char array used to read from a pipe.
This array is used in an infinite while cycle

```
int main() 
{   
    mkfifo("process1_write", 0666); 
    mkfifo("process1_read", 0666); 
    int fd1,fd2;  
    fd1 = open(process1_write, O_RDWR);
    fd2 = open(process1_read, O_RDONLY| O_NONBLOCK);  
    std::string outmsg  = "{process: drv_rtnode_1, message: hi}";
    while (1) 
    { 
        char str1[1050];
        printf("cycle %d\n\t",i++);
        int in = read(fd2, str1, 1024);
        if(in>0)
        {
            printf("message: %s, in: %d\n", str1, in); 
            write(fd1, outmsg.c_str(), outmsg.size());
        }
        else
            printf("No content received\n");
        sleep(1);
    } 
    return 0; 
}
```

As you can see, str1 is instantiated on the stack as a local variable so I'd expect it to be free'd after each while-cycle.

However what I get is the following:

**Cycle 1: receiving data from the PIPE, thus enterning if(in>0)**

```
message: {"msg type": "status inst", "ProcessName": "process1", "StatusDetail": "dettaglio componente"}{"msg type": "status ses", "ProcessName": "process1", "GroupName": "MOT", "GroupSts": "Online", "ActiveSession": "PRI", "StatusDetail": "dettaglio sessione"}, in: 251
```

in = 251, so it's counting the number of characters correctly

**Cycle 2: receiving LESS data from the PIPE**

This time I'm receiving this message: {"state":"alive"}
But here's the printed output:

```
message: {"state":"alive"}tus inst", "ProcessName": "process1", "StatusDetail": "dettaglio componente"}{"msg type": "status ses", "ProcessName": "process1", "GroupName": "MOT", "GroupSts": "Online", "ActiveSession": "PRI", "StatusDetail": "dettaglio sessione"} , in: 17
```

in = 17, so the number of characters is, once again, correctly counted but my array has not been emptied at all

This happens no matter what kind of data I receive.

I also tried changing the code as follows:

```
   char* str1 = new char[1050];
    while (1) 
    { 
        printf("cycle %d\n\t",i++);
        int in = read(fd2, str1, 1024);
        if(in>0)
        {
            printf("message: %s, in: %d\n", str1, in); 
            write(fd1, outmsg.c_str(), outmsg.size());
        }
        else
            printf("No content received\n");
        sleep(1);
        delete[] str1;
        str1 = new char[1050];
    }
```

But nothing has changed. It behaves exactly the same.

Comment: You need to null terminate c-strings.  It looks like your `read` function isn't doing that.

Comment: XY question.  The array _IS_ "freed", and the memory is re-used.  Since the array is not initialized, the memory is not touched.  This program has undefined behavior because you're not null-terminating your strings.  `read` does not do this for you, as data may arrive over several calls, and it does not care whether your data is a string or not.

Comment: @kn0bbulo So what is your question? `I'm receiving this message: {"state":"alive"} ` I do not understand, in your code there is `{process: drv_rtnode_1, message: hi}` yet you show some `{"state":"alive"}` and `{"msg type": "status inst...` ? Where from are these other messages? `receiving LESS data from the PIPE` Yes, this is how it works. But are there _missing_ data from the pipe or are you receiving only _part_ of the data? `printf("message: %s, in: %d\n", str1` When you receive _part_ of the data, `str1` will not be zero terminated.

Comment: You are not using the value of `in` to control how much is printed.  That's the real issue here, and has nothing to do with allocation or deallocation.  The `printf` has format specifiers that could be used that utilizes `in`, or `cout.write()` can be used that would utilize `in`.  Also, what if the data has embedded nulls?  Your way of printing would fail anyway since a null would stop the print at the first null, and not write all `in` characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following:

```
while (1) 
{ 
    char str1[1050];
```

allocates on the function call stack, but does it like this:

```
char str1[1050];
while (1) 
{
```

So the location is reused, and only about 1050 bytes callocated.

The problem is, that for strings a nul terminator is needed:

```
   int in = read(fd2, str1, 1024);
   if (in > 0)
   {
       str1[in] = '\0';
```

Now the overwriting with shorter data does not show prior reads.

Comment: Ok just tried this out and it's great, it works. But the fact that without null termination the characters would all remain sitting there kinda frightens me. If I do add the null terminating character, what happens to all the other characters? Are they actually deleted or are they still sapping memory away?

Comment: @kn0bbulo Those characters remain with indeterminate values. They don't "sap memory away".

Comment: There are 1050 characters allocated, and a #in part of them overwritten. Initially the are "garbage". On function return they disappear.

Comment: @eerorika Thanks. Unfortunately I've never had to work on critical memory management so now that I have to keep track of everything I allocate and deallocate I'm forced to learn all of this in the span of very little time. Thanks again

Comment: @kn0bbulo Operating systems are efficient.  When you "free" memory, it doesn't erase the memory, it just marks it as available to be used again.  That's why you see the old contents on the second iteration.

Comment: `now that I have to keep track of everything I allocate and deallocate` Don't. Use smart pointers, `std::vector`, `unique_ptr`, `shared_ptr` are your friends.

Comment: @kn0bbulo When you allocate the array, the characters in it are indeterminate -- they can be absolutely anything. Don't be surprised if they are equal to (or different from) some value you are thinking of. Indeterminate means that there is no guarantee that they have (or haven't) some specific value. Often, the compiler/runtime will allocate memory in the same place where something was just freed, reusing previous values, since that can be very efficient. This is what happened here (but don't rely on that).